# How can I see the xml DrawerLayout file in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawerlayout

I am creating the XML drawer layout file on android studio but can not previews on android studio am getting this error how can i solve the problem

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff6600"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    tools:context="br.com.appingles.Tela2" >

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assertosTela2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perguntaTela2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:onClick="button2"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:onClick="button3"
        android:text="Button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="button4"
        android:text="Button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:onClick="button1"
        android:text="Button1" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_dr"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="br.com.appingles.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    />
```

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.appingles"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
```

}

I get this error :

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:android.support.v4.widget.Drawer Layout (Fix Build Path, Create Class) Tip: Try to build the project.

Comment: This? compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'

Comment: in your xml file I don't see the drawer.

Comment: It's my first time in the stack, I forgot to add the complete code, but edited and added now complete.

Answer (score 0):

The parent(top most element) of your `layout.xml` must be `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="mainMenu.MainExpandActivity">
```

If everything is proper and if it still doesn't show preview then compile and build your project, then try.

According to [Android developer's page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

**The main content view (the FrameLayout above) must be the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.**

---

**EDIT**

First of all you need to add External Jar

In android studio go to File-> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + symbol -> Library Dependency.

Now search for support library. you will find something like this com.android.support:support-v13

Now, select Jar file named support-v13 (Whatever the version is) and click OK.

**EDIT # 2**

The Palette didn't display your `DrawerLayout` instantly. Actually, it's a normal behavior. After all, the Palette only displays static monolayer views while the `DrawerLayout` is a complicated `ViewGroup` and it has multilayers: the drawer and the content. Meanwhile, `DrawerLayout` is a dynamic View whose effects only could be seen on a device or a simulator. So, feel free to run your `Activity` which loads this layout, and you will see the effect of your layout which contains your `DrawerLayout`

Comment: It's my first time in the stack, I forgot to add the complete code, but edited and added now complete.

Comment: did you compiled and build your project ??

Comment: Yes, the error remains: Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:android.support.v4.widget.Drawer Layout (Fix Build Path, Create Class) Tip: Try to build the project.

Comment: I added, but the error continue. I have this:                                  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1'
}

Comment: Do I need delete the compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' ?

Comment: can you run your code , does the drawer show in emulator ?

Comment: The Palette didn't display your `DrawerLayout` instantly. Actually, it's a normal behavior. After all, the Palette only displays static monolayer views while the `DrawerLayout` is a complicated `ViewGroup` and it has multilayers: the drawer and the content. Meanwhile, `DrawerLayout` is a dynamic View whose effects only could be seen on a device or a simulator. So, feel free to run your Activity which loads this layout, and you will see the effect of your layout which contains your `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: In simple, you cannot view the preview of `DrawerLayout` because its dynamically generated at runtime.

Comment: I don't see nothing in my IDE, the view don't load.

Comment: is my first time in the stack, I accept responses only when they work out?